# AngularJS Pagination orderBy only affects displayed page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have written my code in following manner:

```
<div id="{{item.product.id}}" class="col-xs-12 inventory-row" dir-paginate="item in inventory|itemsPerPage:10|orderFilter:filterMainKeyword|orderBy:getMainInventoryOrderByAttribute():getMainInventorySortOrder()" pagination-id='mainInventory'>
    <div class="item-footer">
        <dir-pagination-controls pagination-id='mainInventory'></dir-pagination-controls>
    </div>
<div>
```

Whenever I try to sort any column, the items in current page get sorted, is there any way I can sort all items?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Flip your filter around

```
item in inventory | orderFilter: filterMainKeyword | itemsPerPage: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Filters in AngularJS are applied in the order you define them. Try ordering the collection before other filters are applied:

```
dir-paginate="item in inventory | orderFilter: filterMainKeyword | orderBy:getMainInventoryOrderByAttribute():getMainInventorySortOrder() | itemsPerPage: 10"
```